# Linq to nhibernate - Where collection contains object with id

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have 2 objects like this

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual int ChildId { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a linq to nhibernate query to select a parent where it contains a child with a specific id. `return x => x.Children.Contains` does not work.  I also tried this.

```
return x => (from y in x.Children where y.ChildId.Equals(childId) select y).Count() > 0
```

My fluent mapping looks like this

```
HasManyToMany<Child>(x => x.Children)
            .Table("ParentsChildren")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ParentId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ChildId");
```

How can I find the parent that contains a child by id?

Comment: I ended up making a composite object consisting of the parent object and the child id.  Then, I mapped it to the `ParentsChildren` table and use that object in my query.  Then I use linq to select the parent(s) from the composite objects returned by my query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which NHibernate version are you using?

If you are using the new NHibernate linq library, then I think you van do something like:

```
var parent = session.Query<Parent>()
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ChildId == childId))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In older versions you had to use `.Linq<T>()` instead of `.Query<T>()`:

```
var parent = session.Linq<Parent>()
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ChildId == childId))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I can't remember if the older NHibernate linq library already supported these kind of queries.