# LINQ Fluent NHIBERNATE .Contains() does not work in QueryOver<> but works in Query<>

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using FNH, i am trying to retrieve categories, using the following:

```
_session.QueryOver<Data.Model.Category>()
                                     .Where(c => tourCreateRequest.Categories.Contains(c.CategoryId))
                                     .List()
                                     .Select(_categoryMapper.CreateCategory)
                                     .ToList();
```

But I get an error at the **.Contains()** method :

> Unrecognised method call:
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]:Boolean Contains(Int64)

Why am I getting that error, what is wrong?

I went through some posts, and then changed my query to (below), and this works with Query<>.

```
_session.Query<Data.Model.Category>()
                                     .Where(c => tourCreateRequest.Categories.Contains(c.CategoryId))
                                     .ToList()
                                     .Select(_categoryMapper.CreateCategory)
                                     .ToList();
```

I thought QueryOver<> is the latest and greatest and should be used instead of Query<>.

What is the issue with the way I am using QueryOver<> as shown above?

Comment: I Think you need to read this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328565/nhibernate3-query-vs-queryover

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, how can I perform the same thing using .Contains() using QueryOver<>?

Comment: I like this solution better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739129/linq-to-nhibernate-where-collection-contains-object-with-id

Comment: @JacobBrewer, that solutions does not work because it only checks with a single childId. Need an IN clause.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer. Thanks to the post at: [NHibernate using QueryOver with WHERE IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408781/nhibernate-using-queryover-with-where-in)

```
var categories = _session.QueryOver<Data.Model.Category>()
                                     .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.CategoryId).IsIn(ArrayofCategoryIds)
                                     .List()
                                     .Select(_categoryMapper.CreateCategory)
                                     .ToList();
```

I had to use the WhereRestrictionOn()

Answer (score 8):

This is tangentially related issue and this seemed like the best place to put it.

```
_session.Query<SomeType>.Where(t => someEnumerable.Contains(t))
```

was not working.

In my case `someEnumerable` was NOT a `List<SomeType>`, but rather a `HashSet<SomeType>`. Apparently, NH really wants it to be a list. So, I did this instead and it worked.

```
var someEnumerableList = someEnumerable.ToList();
_session.Query<SomeType>.Where(t => someEnumerableList.Contains(t)
```

Also, FWIW, I was under the impression that `Query<T>` was the new preferred way to go and that `QueryOver<T>` was the less preferred way, because `Query<T>` returns IQueryable, meaning that it should be a little easier to test, and theoretically swap out ORMs.

Comment: Your call to `ToList()` executes the query, ie it causes a server round trip returning all records of type `SomeType`. I think the preferred option would be to just get the subset from the server that satisfies the `Where()` clause. It seems that at least for simple cases this works: `session.Query<Foo>().Where(f => setOfIds.Contains(f.SomeId))` and where `SomeId` is of type `Guid`. We use version 5.1.0 of NHibernate.

Comment: IMPORTANT: It's not that NHibernate "really wants it to be a list." The underlying reason that HashSet<T> doesn't work as expected is that HashSet<T> relies on the result of `GetHashCode()` remaining constant for all its child objects. And crucially, when you implement NHibernate you usually override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in a base entity... The result is that when you save your entity and it gets an ID, the value of `GetHashCode()` for that entity changes, and now HashSet<T> can't find it within itself anymore. List<T> doesn't rely on `GetHashCode()`, so it works.

Answer (score -1):

like this:

```
    query = query.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.DescricaoDoProduto.Homogenize()).IsInsensitiveLike
(filter.Description.Homogenize());
```